# Bootstrap grid space between divs increases not supposed to happen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

The space between the div's are increasing if the width of the screen increases too, but that's not supposed to happen they need to be close to each other and when there is space left another div beside them so from 3 divs to 4 divs in one row.

[image: How it should look and looks at 320px]
How it should look and looks at 320px

[image: What happens when I increase the pixels to 506px this is not supposed to happen]
What happens when I increase the pixels to 506px this is not supposed to happen

[image: This is the idea of how it all should look]
This is the idea of how it all should look

[image: This is how it looks on desktop. This is one is alright]
This is how it looks on desktop. This is one is alright

This is my html code I think you won't need the css. I want it to look like photo 3 and that if I increase the screen size with repsonsive tool from browsers that the space between the grey small_picture div's doesn't increase.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--<editor-fold desc="Bedrijfsfoto's Desktop">-->
<span style="color: #e94e18; font-size: 15px;">Bedrijfsfoto's</span>
<br>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="big_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="70px" height="70px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="desktop_small_pictures">

  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="40px" height="40px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sp_margin col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="40px" height="40px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sp_margin col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="40px" height="40px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sp_margin col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="40px" height="40px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sp_margin col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="40px" height="40px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sp_margin col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="40px" height="40px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="sp_margin col-md-1 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="40px" height="40px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>

<script>
  $("#big_picture").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
  });
  $(".small_picture").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
  });
</script>

<br>
<!--</editor-fold>-->

<!--<editor-fold desc="Bedrijfsfoto's Mobile">-->

<div class="row" id="mobile_small_pictures">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="small_picture">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
        <span>Foto uploaden</span>
        <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="small_picture">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
        <span>Foto uploaden</span>
        <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="small_picture">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
        <span>Foto uploaden</span>
        <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="small_picture">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
        <span>Foto uploaden</span>
        <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="small_picture">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
        <span>Foto uploaden</span>
        <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="small_picture">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
        <span>Foto uploaden</span>
        <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="small_picture">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
        <span>Foto uploaden</span>
        <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="small_picture">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
        <span>Foto uploaden</span>
        <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="small_picture">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
        <span>Foto uploaden</span>
        <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


</div>

<br>
<!--</editor-fold>-->
```

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: No, not yet....

Comment: Edit the question with the problem you are having currently please.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this right?
Will add explanation soon.

```css
@media (min-width:1000px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    flex: 1;
  }
}


/*<editor-fold desc="Big Picture">*/

#big_picture {
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #c3bdbd;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#big_picture img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#big_picture a {
  color: black;
}


/*</editor-fold>*/


/*<editor-fold desc="Small Picture">*/

#mobile_small_pictures {
  display: inherit;
}

#desktop_small_pictures {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.small_picture {
  background-color: #ededed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #c3bdbd;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.small_picture img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.small_picture a {
  color: black;
}

.sp_margin {
  margin-left: 5.8% !important;
}


/*</editor-fold>*/


/*<editor-fold desc="Belangrijke Voorzieningen">*/

#checkboxTable {
  width: 50%;
}

#checkboxTable tr {
  background: white;
}


/*</editor-fold>*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  /*display none of wel*/
  #desktop_small_pictures,
  #big_picture {
    display: none;
  }
  #mobile_small_pictures {
    display: inherit;
  }
  /*small picture*/
  .small_picture {
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  /*belangrijke voorzieningen*/
  #checkboxTable {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*bedrijfspagina*/
  #bedrijfspagina {
    margin-top: 8em;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row" id="mobile_small_pictures">


  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-1">
    <div class="small_picture">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/twitter-square/256/twitter-square-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px">
      <span>Foto uploaden</span>
      <a href="uploader.html" class="clickableDiv"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: will fix the desktop view in 30 min.

Comment: Doesn't work. The space between the div's still increases when screen gets wider

Comment: It solves half the problem. I just need to have something that there doesn't come too much space between the div's

Comment: The issue is really trivial. There must be some overlapping property in your code. Show it to me, it will be fixed. Put it https://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: Desktop version is not the problem right now. But look at the space diffrences at 320px and 420px. The space needs to be the same

Comment: Check the [edit](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/eeMdJM) and let me know if that's what you are expecting. Image is in the center now.

Comment: Use responsive browser tool. Look at 320px and 500px you see there is much more space between the div's. At 320px space between div 1 and div2 is like 10px and at 500px the space is 50px. But I want it to be 10px at each width. I can explain this better with a GIF or something but that isn't possible I think

Comment: send me email of picture of the error. here is my email id : dhavaljardosh@gmail.com